# Title of question (populated from search) does not persist through google sign-up

Tags: bug, title, unregistered-users, sign-up

**Steps to recreate**:

1. go to serverfault.com as an unregistered user
2. click 'ask question'
3. when shown the 'please be nice, and please search first' page, enter a search term in the input box: 'who loves foo?'
4. check box at bottom of page, proceed
5. at question form, the title input is pre-populated as 'who loves foo?'. edit it to be 'who loves bar?', and enter 'baz does' in the textarea for the question
6. click 'Sign in using Google' at bottom of page, follow signin flow
7. get returned to the question form

**Expected Result**

At #7, title input box should contain 'who loves bar?', and textarea should contain 'baz does'

**Observed Result**

At #7, title input box contains 'who loves foo?', and textarea contains 'baz does'